# Can I open a group of buffers at once?

Tags: buffers

When I need to reopen `vim` for some reason (vim updated, reboot, etc), I need to manually open a bunch of buffers when I start up.

Is there some way I can save the current set of buffers open in some kind of list and open them all as a group the next time I start vim?

Comment: @aharris88 - A yes, that does appear to be a proper solution, I just missed it. I'm more interested in recovery of a session after quitting vim, so perhaps there's a simpler solution other than using `:mksession` and saving session state to a file?

Answer (score 2):

You can save your current session to a file with `:mksession filename` and then restore it by running vim with `vim -S filename`.  You can find the full documentation with `:help views-sessions`.